# Java System.setProperty add project path in front of my path

Tags: java

I want to set as system property a file path from resources folder.

```
String path = MainCore.class.getClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver-76.0.3809.68.exe").toExternalForm();

System.out.println(path);
//file:/D:/JavaIDEA/projname/target/classes/chromedriver-76.0.3809.68.exe

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
//IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: 
//D:\JavaIDEA\projname\file:\D:\JavaIDEA\projname\target\classes\chromedriver-76.0.3809.68.exe
```

Why when I `setProperty`, it add in front of my path the path of project?

I also tried this: `path = path.replace("/", "\\\\");` - same result

I'm using Windows.

Comment: I'm using windows. I don't think I understand your comment.

Comment: Seems like webdriver path is either relative to your app' folder, or selenium doesn't expect it to be the URI that you're giving it, and trying to treat that URI as a relative path. Why do you use the URL's external form, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
String absolutePath = new File(MainCore.class.getClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver-76.0.3809.68.exe").getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
```

Comment: It works. I don't get why with `replace("/", "\\\\")` didn't worked. It's same thing. When I export my project as jar, this will still work?

Comment: @KunLun, it's not the same thing. how about `file:` URL schema identifier in front that you had before and don't have now?

Comment: Ye, that is the difference. What exactly `file:/` represent and why just don't understand it?

Comment: @KunLun 'toExternalForm()' actually gives you a URL with access protocol  which is file://. Here we tried to form the proper disk path using File API and use it. Hope you will accept the answer

Comment: I forgot `getResources` represent an `URL`, thanks.